# How to get selectedrow cell value from a gridview into the body of an email in my asp.net c# web forms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to get cell values from selected rows of specified gridviews, and use those values in the body of an email.  The email gets delivered, but instead of having the cell values in the body of the email, it has "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField".  This is the code I am using for the body of the email:

```
msg.Body = "A review for document number " + gv_vendor_doc.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text + " " + "titled " + gv_vendor_doc.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + " " + "for vendor " + gv_vendor_list.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + " " + "has been submitted for your review.";
```

The above code works as expected when I run it on my localhost, but not when I try it on the production web server.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an asp.net c# web forms application.

Thanks,
J

Here is the gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView 
        ID="gv_vendor_doc" 
        runat="server" 
        AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4"
        DataKeyNames="doc_id_pk" 
        DataSourceID="sdc_gv_vendor_doc" 
        EmptyDataText="There are no records to display." 
        GridLines="Both" 
        ForeColor="#333333" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_vendor_doc_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AccessibleHeaderText="Document ID" DataField="doc_id_pk" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="doc_id_pk" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Document Type" DataField="doc_type" HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="doc_type" >
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Document Title" DataField="doc_title" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="doc_title" >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AccessibleHeaderText="Organization" DataField="org" HeaderText="Organization" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="org" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AccessibleHeaderText="Department" DataField="dept" HeaderText="Department" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="dept" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Document Description" DataField="doc_desc" HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="doc_desc" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor ID" DataField="vendor_nm" HeaderText="Vendor ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="vendor_nm" Visible="false" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AccessibleHeaderText="Status" DataField="rvw_status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gv_hdr_style" SortExpression="rvw_status">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("doc_path") %>' runat="server" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#BCC7D9" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#044C92" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#044C92" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#BCC7D9" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gv_vendor_list" 
    runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    DataSourceID="sdc_gv_vendor_list" 
    CssClass="gv_padding" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="vendor_id_pk" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    GridLines="Both" 
    ForeColor="#333333"
    EmptyDataText="Choose a vendor in the dropdown list above" 
    PageSize="5"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_vendor_list_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor ID" DataField="vendor_id_pk" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor Name" DataField="vendor_nm" HeaderText="Vendor">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Street Direction" DataField="st_dir" HeaderText="Direction">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor Address" DataField="vendor_st_add" HeaderText="Mailing Address">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Street Type" DataField="st_type" HeaderText="Type">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor City" DataField="vendor_city" HeaderText="City">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Zip Code" DataField="vendor_zip" HeaderText="Zip Code">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor Phone Number" DataField="vendor_prim_ph" HeaderText="Phone">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Vendor Active" DataField="vendor_active_yn_list" HeaderText="Active">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_hdr_style" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>        
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#BCC7D9" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#044C92" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#044C92" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gv_padding" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="gv_padding" BackColor="#BCC7D9" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: GridView markup please !!

Comment: Code and Markup seems fine to me. What does gv_vendor_doc.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text shows when debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed all of the files from the server and then moved them back and everything started to work.  Thanks for the help.